# Making dictionary linked by parameters to selected values?

Tags: python, xml, dictionary

Aim is to automatically/periodically make an XML-file containing dynamic values selected from Domoticz' data as available elsewhere in the Python-script. Resulting XML-file like shown below.

```
<response>
  <value1>0.0</value1>
  <value2>10.0</value2>
  <value3>10.0</value3>
  <value4>0.0</value4>
  <value5>0.00</value5>
  <time_stamp>20161215 20:44</time_stamp>
</response>
```

For making such XML-file a starting point in Python could be a dictionary, because from a dictionary by means of dicttoxml you rather easily can make an XML-file.

**Question** then: how to compile a dictionary which parameterically contains selected dynamic values from Domoticz, and is readable by dicttoxml?

In my opinion it means:

1. make a default list-structure for the dictionary
2. values in that structure represented by parameters
3. those parameters to be linked to selected values available in the Python-script
4. read-out function to fill the parameters, plus generation of dictionary

*Correct/feasible approach? 
Any Python-script known/available realizing that job/sequence?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some further search related to the Python Dictionary provided sufficient hints to make a script, tested as extension to a read-out script for kWh-meter type DDS238-1ZN. That script provided the dynamic links to the dictionary.

It proves that the concept as mentioned in the first question is correct.

```
# --------------------------------------------------
# Make XML-file for DDS238-1ZN Read-out
# --------------------------------------------------
# Take care of extra dependencies
import dicttoxml
# Create the default dictionary
DDS238_dict = {'gauge_power': 1.2, 'gauge_temp': 20.4, 'gauge_vpv': 150, 'gauge_iac': 1.5, 'energy_today': 2.5, 'energy_total': 45.00, 'time_stamp': 0}
print(DDS238_dict)
# Link the directory to dynamic values in the Python-script (or fill-in placeholder values)
DDS238_dict['gauge_power'] = ActivPower
DDS238_dict['gauge_temp'] = 20.1
DDS238_dict['gauge_vpv'] = VOLTAGE
DDS238_dict['gauge_iac'] = CURRENT
DDS238_dict['energy_today'] = Wh_today
DDS238_dict['energy_total'] = Wh_life
DDS238_dict['time_stamp'] = now
print(DDS238_dict)
# Convert dictionary to XML-file
DDS238_xml = dicttoxml.dicttoxml(DDS238_dict)
print(DDS238_xml)
```

Obviously the print-lines are optional (for testing).

;-) Easy enough, if you know ........